# How do you make a macro in excel not show the selections being made

Tags: vba, excel

I know there's a property to add in the beginning of the macro so that all the selections and deselection happen in the background and are not shown on the sheet. I think I had to disable some property at the beginning of the macro and enable it at the end. Does anyone remember what it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Just remember to call this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end (and make sure you have error handling.  If it fails and you do not set it back to true, the application will appear to be frozen forever.

Comment: These two lines will speed up certain macros by a factor of 10 or more.

Comment: When changing settings like that it's usually a good idea to have an error handler that restores ScreenUpdating back to true.  That way if your function crashes you're not stuck with wonky settings.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to avoid working with selections altogether.

Other than to initially determine which cell/object the user wants to carry out an action on, you just refer directly to the objects you need to.

To give a very simple example, instead of

```
Range("G18").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "123"
```

You use

```
Range("G18").Value = "123"
```

[Here's a good introductory article on this.](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/beyond_the_macro_recorder/)